# Signal and slots for Qt console application?

Tags: qt, console

I wonder if I should use signal and slots with my own console object? Or are they only used with a GUI?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use signals and slots in a console application. You can subclass `QCoreApplication` or just use one as an event loop. In `main()`, create a `QCoreApplication` object along with any of your own objects that use signals and slots, connect the signals and then call `.exec()` on the `QCoreApplication` object. Make sure you have some way to signal the `QCoreApplication` to quit.